# AddPostRenderCallback in ItemTemplate is not getting called in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, display-template, postback

Hi I have an item template. In which below is the code for the AddPostRenderCallback.

```
 AddPostRenderCallback(context, function () {
                    alert("Inside Addpostrendercallback");
                });
```

This piece of code does not get executed. I tried using the developer tools debuger, still the debug point on alert is not hit. It simply doesnt go inside the function.

When i `step on to` in the debugger on the  `AddPostRenderCallback` function it goes to clienttemplate.js and debugger is on `AddRenderCallback(b,"OnPostRender",a,false)   undefined`. I think false attribute is causing it to not fire. Any suggestions?

Full code

Test Events Item

```
    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
    <mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
    <mso:TemplateHidden msdt:dt="string">0</mso:TemplateHidden>
    <mso:MasterPageDescription msdt:dt="string"></mso:MasterPageDescription>
    <mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106603</mso:ContentTypeId>
    <mso:TargetControlType msdt:dt="string">;#SearchResults;#</mso:TargetControlType>
    <mso:HtmlDesignAssociated msdt:dt="string">1</mso:HtmlDesignAssociated>
    <mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">&#39;Title&#39;:&#39;Title&#39;,&#39;RefinableString103&#39;:&#39;RefinableString103&#39;,&#39;RefinableString102&#39;:&#39;RefinableString102&#39;,&#39;RefinableDate04&#39;:&#39;RefinableDate04&#39;,&#39;RefinableString100&#39;:&#39;RefinableString100&#39;,&#39;RefinableDate00&#39;:&#39;RefinableDate00&#39;,&#39;Path&#39;:&#39;Path&#39;,&#39;Description&#39;:&#39;Description&#39;,&#39;EditorOWSUSER&#39;:&#39;EditorOWSUSER&#39;,&#39;LastModifiedTime&#39;:&#39;LastModifiedTime&#39;,&#39;CollapsingStatus&#39;:&#39;CollapsingStatus&#39;,&#39;DocId&#39;:&#39;DocId&#39;,&#39;HitHighlightedSummary&#39;:&#39;HitHighlightedSummary&#39;,&#39;HitHighlightedProperties&#39;:&#39;HitHighlightedProperties&#39;,&#39;FileExtension&#39;:&#39;FileExtension&#39;,&#39;ViewsLifeTime&#39;:&#39;ViewsLifeTime&#39;,&#39;ParentLink&#39;:&#39;ParentLink&#39;,&#39;FileType&#39;:&#39;FileType&#39;,&#39;IsContainer&#39;:&#39;IsContainer&#39;,&#39;SecondaryFileExtension&#39;:&#39;SecondaryFileExtension&#39;,&#39;DisplayAuthor&#39;:&#39;DisplayAuthor&#39;,&#39;PictureHeight&#39;:&#39;PictureHeight&#39;,&#39;PictureWidth&#39;:&#39;PictureWidth&#39;,&#39;ImageDateCreated&#39;:&#39;ImageDateCreated&#39;,&#39;PictureThumbnailURL&#39;:&#39;PictureThumbnailURL&#39;,&#39;PictureURL&#39;:&#39;PictureURL&#39;,&#39;AgnBlurbOWSTEXT&#39;:&#39;AgnBlurbOWSTEXT&#39;,&#39;AgnArticleTypeOWSCHCS&#39;:&#39;AgnArticleTypeOWSCHCS&#39;,&#39;ArticleStartDateOWSDATE&#39;:&#39;ArticleStartDateOWSDATE&#39;,&#39;PublishingImage&#39;:&#39;PublishingImage&#39;</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping> 
    <mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview msdt:dt="string">https:/dev.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev/_catalogs/masterpage/Display%20Templates/Search/It.html, Conversion successful.</mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview>
<mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded msdt:dt="string">True</mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded>
<mso:CrawlerXSLFile msdt:dt="string"></mso:CrawlerXSLFile>
<mso:HtmlDesignPreviewUrl msdt:dt="string"></mso:HtmlDesignPreviewUrl>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
    </xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        Type.registerNamespace('search.eventdate');
        search.eventdate = function () {
            var itemInfo = {};
            var init = function (context, elmId) {

                var eStartDate = $getItemValue(context, "RefinableDate00");
                var eEndDate = $getItemValue(context, "RefinableDate04");
                var Location = $getItemValue(context, "RefinableString100");
                // Store item info
                itemInfo[elmId] = {};
                itemInfo[elmId]["EventStartDate"] = eStartDate;
                itemInfo[elmId]["EventEndDate"] = eEndDate;
                itemInfo[elmId]["Location"] = Location;
                itemInfo[elmId]["EventDivId"] = context.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId();
                // Add an on post render callback, this will be excuted when all the results are rendered


                context.OnPostRender = function () {
                    alert('hello world');
                    get(elmId);
                };



                //AddPostRenderCallback(context, function () {
                 //   $(".content-news-item-date2").css("color", "red");
                  //  get(elmId);
                //});
            },

            get = function (elmId) {
                console.log("In get fn for " + elmId);
            },
            // Set the userGUID as class name to the SPAN element
            setClass = function (elmId, userGuid) {
            },
            // Write the document FollowStatus to all elements with the same GUID
            render = function (elmId, userGuid) {
            },
            quickRender = function (elmId, userGuid) {
            };
            return {
                init: init
            };
        }();
    </script>


    <div>
        <!--#_

                    var locationOffset = "";
            var offsetTime = "";
        function getUser(currentItemObject) {

            var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
            console.log("getting userid method: " + userid);
            var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
            console.log("getting requestUri method: " + requestUri);
            var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                url: requestUri,
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                headers: requestHeaders,
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError
            }); function onSuccess(data, request) {
                var loginName = data.d.LoginName;
                    getUserProfileProperty(loginName,"SPS-Location",currentItemObject);
            } function onError(error) {
                console.log("Error on retrieving current user.");
            }
        }
            function getUserProfileProperty(loginName, property, currentItemObject) {
            var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getuserprofilepropertyfor(accountName='" + escape(loginName) + "', propertyname='" + property + "')";
            var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
            $.ajax({
             async: false,
                url: requestUri,
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                headers: requestHeaders,
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError
            }); function onSuccess(data, request) {
                var fetchedProperty = data.d.GetUserProfilePropertyFor;
                  var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
                            if (siteUrl != null && siteUrl != "") {
                                if (siteUrl.indexOf("/sites/") != -1) { siteUrl = siteUrl.split("sites"); siteUrl = siteUrl[0];}
                            }
                            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
                            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Locations');
                            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
                           camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgnLocation'/>" + "<Value Type='TaxonomyFieldType'>" + fetchedProperty + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>");
                            var collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
                            var locationURL = "";
                            var isActive = "";
                            clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(AgnOffset,AgnLocation)');
                            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                                console.log("Inside the async function");
                                if (collListItem.get_count() == 0) {
                                }
                                    else {
                                var enumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
                                while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                                    var item = enumerator.get_current();
                                    locationOffset = item.get_item('AgnOffset');
                                    locationOffset = locationOffset *0.01;
                                    var eventStartDate =  currentItemObject.RefinableDate00;
                                    var targetTime = new Date(eventStartDate);
                                    //get the timezone offset from local time in minutes
                                    var tzDifference = locationOffset * 60;
                                    //convert the offset to milliseconds, add to targetTime, and make a new Date
                                     offsetTime = new Date(targetTime.getTime() + tzDifference * 60 * 1000);
                                    //alert(eventStartDate + offsetTime);


                                }
                                    }

                            },
                               function (s, a) {
                                   console.error(a.get_message());
                               });


               }function onError(error) {
                alert("Error on retrieving current user location:" + error.responseText);
            }
        }


                function formatAMPM(date) {
                  var hours = date.getHours();
                  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
                  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
                  hours = hours % 12;
                  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
                  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
                  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;

                  return strTime;

                }





                if(!$isNull(ctx.CurrentItem) && !$isNull(ctx.ClientControl)){

                 var id = ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId();
                     var itemId = id + Srch.U.Ids.item;
                      var eventStartDate =  $getItemValue(ctx, "RefinableDate00");
                      var s = formatAMPM(new Date(eventStartDate.inputValue));
                      var eventEndDate =  $getItemValue(ctx, "RefinableDate04");
                      var Location = $getItemValue(ctx,"RefinableString100");
                     if(Location != "") {} else {Location=Location; }
                    getUser(ctx.CurrentItem);

                    var startYear = new Date(eventStartDate.inputValue).format('yyyy');
                    var startDate = new Date(eventStartDate.inputValue).format('dd');
                    var startMonth = new Date(eventStartDate.inputValue).format('MMM');
                     var endYear ="";
                     var endDate = "";
                     var endMonth = "";
                     var endPMAM = "";
                    if(eventEndDate!="")
            {
                         endYear = new Date(eventEndDate.inputValue).format('yyyy');
                         endDate = new Date(eventEndDate.inputValue).format('dd');
                         endMonth = new Date(eventEndDate.inputValue).format('MMM');
                         endPMAM = formatAMPM(new Date(eventEndDate.inputValue));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      endYear = "endYear";
                      endDate = "endDate";
                      endMonth = "endMonth";
                      endPMAM = "EndAMPM";
                    }
                        var EventDivId = id + "EventContainer";
                        search.eventdate.init(ctx, EventDivId);




                  _#-->
        <div class="content-news-item" >
            <div class="content-news-item-icon">
                <div class="content-news-item-icon-in">
                    <div class="content-news-icon">
                        <!-- _#= ctx.CurrentItem.PublishingImage =#_
                          <img src="_#= ctx.CurrentItem.PublishingImage =#_" width="570" height="270" alt="_#= $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.Title) =#_">-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-news-item-info">
                <div class="content-news-item-date">_#= startYear + " "+ startMonth + " " + startDate + " To " + endYear +   endMonth + " " + endDate  =#_</div>
                <div class="content-news-item-date">_#= s + " -  " + endPMAM =#_</div>
                <div class="content-news-item-date2">_#= Location =#_</div>
                <div class="content-news-item-date2">_#= offsetTime + " offset time" =#_</div>

                <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(EventDivId) =#_">
                    <div class="EventDateUserClass">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="content-news-item-date2">
                    <a href='_#= _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List=" +  $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.RefinableString103) + "&CacheControl=1&ID=" +  $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.RefinableString102) + "&Using=event.ics"  =#_'>Add to OutLook</a>
                </div>
                <div class="content-news-item-title"><a href="_#= ctx.CurrentItem.Path =#_" class="slide-title">_#= $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.Title) =#_</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--#_
                       }
        _#-->
    </div>
</body>



</html>
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to register your custom method as follows in the Script Block of your display template:

```
Srch.U.registerRenderTemplateByName("mycustomfunction", MyCustomFunction);

function MyCustomFunction(ctx) {
     ....
}
```

And then call your function from the html part(respectively from the javascript block in your html):

```
Srch.U.getRenderTemplateCollection().mycustomfunction(ctx)
```

In the custom function you can call your module/your function search.eventdate.init(ctx, EventDivId);

Answer (score 2):

try it as below. Make sure its inside `<!--#_  _#-->` block

```
<!--#_
AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function(){
   alert('Hi');
   CallAnotherMethod("Hi");
});
CallAnotherMethod(str)
{
    alert(str);
}
_#-->
```

Another way to reference it is as below:

```
ctx.OnPostRender = function() {
    alert('hello world');
};
```

**Edit** Based on comments check the below updated display template code:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
    <mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
    <mso:TemplateHidden msdt:dt="string">0</mso:TemplateHidden>
    <mso:MasterPageDescription msdt:dt="string"></mso:MasterPageDescription>
    <mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106603</mso:ContentTypeId>
    <mso:TargetControlType msdt:dt="string">;#SearchResults;#</mso:TargetControlType>
    <mso:HtmlDesignAssociated msdt:dt="string">1</mso:HtmlDesignAssociated>
    <mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">&#39;Title&#39;:&#39;Title&#39;,&#39;RefinableString103&#39;:&#39;RefinableString103&#39;,&#39;RefinableString102&#39;:&#39;RefinableString102&#39;,&#39;RefinableDate04&#39;:&#39;RefinableDate04&#39;,&#39;RefinableString100&#39;:&#39;RefinableString100&#39;,&#39;RefinableDate00&#39;:&#39;RefinableDate00&#39;,&#39;Path&#39;:&#39;Path&#39;,&#39;Description&#39;:&#39;Description&#39;,&#39;EditorOWSUSER&#39;:&#39;EditorOWSUSER&#39;,&#39;LastModifiedTime&#39;:&#39;LastModifiedTime&#39;,&#39;CollapsingStatus&#39;:&#39;CollapsingStatus&#39;,&#39;DocId&#39;:&#39;DocId&#39;,&#39;HitHighlightedSummary&#39;:&#39;HitHighlightedSummary&#39;,&#39;HitHighlightedProperties&#39;:&#39;HitHighlightedProperties&#39;,&#39;FileExtension&#39;:&#39;FileExtension&#39;,&#39;ViewsLifeTime&#39;:&#39;ViewsLifeTime&#39;,&#39;ParentLink&#39;:&#39;ParentLink&#39;,&#39;FileType&#39;:&#39;FileType&#39;,&#39;IsContainer&#39;:&#39;IsContainer&#39;,&#39;SecondaryFileExtension&#39;:&#39;SecondaryFileExtension&#39;,&#39;DisplayAuthor&#39;:&#39;DisplayAuthor&#39;,&#39;PictureHeight&#39;:&#39;PictureHeight&#39;,&#39;PictureWidth&#39;:&#39;PictureWidth&#39;,&#39;ImageDateCreated&#39;:&#39;ImageDateCreated&#39;,&#39;PictureThumbnailURL&#39;:&#39;PictureThumbnailURL&#39;,&#39;PictureURL&#39;:&#39;PictureURL&#39;,&#39;AgnBlurbOWSTEXT&#39;:&#39;AgnBlurbOWSTEXT&#39;,&#39;AgnArticleTypeOWSCHCS&#39;:&#39;AgnArticleTypeOWSCHCS&#39;,&#39;ArticleStartDateOWSDATE&#39;:&#39;ArticleStartDateOWSDATE&#39;,&#39;PublishingImage&#39;:&#39;PublishingImage&#39;</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping> 
    <mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview msdt:dt="string">https:/dev.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev/_catalogs/masterpage/Display%20Templates/Search/It.html, Conversion successful.</mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview>
<mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded msdt:dt="string">True</mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded>
<mso:CrawlerXSLFile msdt:dt="string"></mso:CrawlerXSLFile>
<mso:HtmlDesignPreviewUrl msdt:dt="string"></mso:HtmlDesignPreviewUrl>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
    </xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        Type.registerNamespace('search.eventdate');
        search.eventdate = function () {
            var itemInfo = {};
            var init = function (context, elmId) {

                var eStartDate = $getItemValue(context, "RefinableDate00");
                var eEndDate = $getItemValue(context, "RefinableDate04");
                var Location = $getItemValue(context, "RefinableString100");
                // Store item info
                itemInfo[elmId] = {};
                itemInfo[elmId]["EventStartDate"] = eStartDate;
                itemInfo[elmId]["EventEndDate"] = eEndDate;
                itemInfo[elmId]["Location"] = Location;
                itemInfo[elmId]["EventDivId"] = context.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId();
                // Add an on post render callback, this will be excuted when all the results are rendered

            },

            get = function (elmId) {
                console.log("In get fn for " + elmId);
            },
            // Set the userGUID as class name to the SPAN element
            setClass = function (elmId, userGuid) {
            },
            // Write the document FollowStatus to all elements with the same GUID
            render = function (elmId, userGuid) {
            },
            quickRender = function (elmId, userGuid) {
            };
            return {
                init: init
            };
        }();
    </script>


    <div>
        <!--#_

                    var locationOffset = "";
            var offsetTime = "";
        function getUser(currentItemObject) {

            var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
            console.log("getting userid method: " + userid);
            var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
            console.log("getting requestUri method: " + requestUri);
            var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                url: requestUri,
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                headers: requestHeaders,
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError
            }); function onSuccess(data, request) {
                var loginName = data.d.LoginName;
                    getUserProfileProperty(loginName,"SPS-Location",currentItemObject);
            } function onError(error) {
                console.log("Error on retrieving current user.");
            }
        }
            function getUserProfileProperty(loginName, property, currentItemObject) {
            var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getuserprofilepropertyfor(accountName='" + escape(loginName) + "', propertyname='" + property + "')";
            var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
            $.ajax({
             async: false,
                url: requestUri,
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                headers: requestHeaders,
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError
            }); function onSuccess(data, request) {
                var fetchedProperty = data.d.GetUserProfilePropertyFor;
                  var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
                            if (siteUrl != null && siteUrl != "") {
                                if (siteUrl.indexOf("/sites/") != -1) { siteUrl = siteUrl.split("sites"); siteUrl = siteUrl[0];}
                            }
                            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
                            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Locations');
                            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
                           camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='AgnLocation'/>" + "<Value Type='TaxonomyFieldType'>" + fetchedProperty + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>");
                            var collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
                            var locationURL = "";
                            var isActive = "";
                            clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(AgnOffset,AgnLocation)');
                            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                                console.log("Inside the async function");
                                if (collListItem.get_count() == 0) {
                                }
                                    else {
                                var enumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
                                while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                                    var item = enumerator.get_current();
                                    locationOffset = item.get_item('AgnOffset');
                                    locationOffset = locationOffset *0.01;
                                    var eventStartDate =  currentItemObject.RefinableDate00;
                                    var targetTime = new Date(eventStartDate);
                                    //get the timezone offset from local time in minutes
                                    var tzDifference = locationOffset * 60;
                                    //convert the offset to milliseconds, add to targetTime, and make a new Date
                                     offsetTime = new Date(targetTime.getTime() + tzDifference * 60 * 1000);
                                    //alert(eventStartDate + offsetTime);


                                }
                                    }

                            },
                               function (s, a) {
                                   console.error(a.get_message());
                               });


               }function onError(error) {
                alert("Error on retrieving current user location:" + error.responseText);
            }
        }


                function formatAMPM(date) {
                  var hours = date.getHours();
                  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
                  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
                  hours = hours % 12;
                  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
                  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
                  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;

                  return strTime;

                }





                if(!$isNull(ctx.CurrentItem) && !$isNull(ctx.ClientControl)){

                 var id = ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId();
                     var itemId = id + Srch.U.Ids.item;
                      var eventStartDate =  $getItemValue(ctx, "RefinableDate00");
                      var s = formatAMPM(new Date(eventStartDate.inputValue));
                      var eventEndDate =  $getItemValue(ctx, "RefinableDate04");
                      var Location = $getItemValue(ctx,"RefinableString100");
                     if(Location != "") {} else {Location=Location; }
                    getUser(ctx.CurrentItem);

                    var startYear = new Date(eventStartDate.inputValue).format('yyyy');
                    var startDate = new Date(eventStartDate.inputValue).format('dd');
                    var startMonth = new Date(eventStartDate.inputValue).format('MMM');
                     var endYear ="";
                     var endDate = "";
                     var endMonth = "";
                     var endPMAM = "";
                    if(eventEndDate!="")
            {
                         endYear = new Date(eventEndDate.inputValue).format('yyyy');
                         endDate = new Date(eventEndDate.inputValue).format('dd');
                         endMonth = new Date(eventEndDate.inputValue).format('MMM');
                         endPMAM = formatAMPM(new Date(eventEndDate.inputValue));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      endYear = "endYear";
                      endDate = "endDate";
                      endMonth = "endMonth";
                      endPMAM = "EndAMPM";
                    }
                        var EventDivId = id + "EventContainer";
                        search.eventdate.init(ctx, EventDivId);




                  _#-->
        <div class="content-news-item" >
            <div class="content-news-item-icon">
                <div class="content-news-item-icon-in">
                    <div class="content-news-icon">
                        <!-- _#= ctx.CurrentItem.PublishingImage =#_
                          <img src="_#= ctx.CurrentItem.PublishingImage =#_" width="570" height="270" alt="_#= $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.Title) =#_">-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-news-item-info">
                <div class="content-news-item-date">_#= startYear + " "+ startMonth + " " + startDate + " To " + endYear +   endMonth + " " + endDate  =#_</div>
                <div class="content-news-item-date">_#= s + " -  " + endPMAM =#_</div>
                <div class="content-news-item-date2">_#= Location =#_</div>
                <div class="content-news-item-date2">_#= offsetTime + " offset time" =#_</div>

                <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(EventDivId) =#_">
                    <div class="EventDateUserClass">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="content-news-item-date2">
                    <a href='_#= _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List=" +  $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.RefinableString103) + "&CacheControl=1&ID=" +  $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.RefinableString102) + "&Using=event.ics"  =#_'>Add to OutLook</a>
                </div>
                <div class="content-news-item-title"><a href="_#= ctx.CurrentItem.Path =#_" class="slide-title">_#= $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.Title) =#_</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--#_
                       }

         AddPostRenderCallback(context, function () {
                    $(".content-news-item-date2").css("color", "red");
            alert("inside postrendercallback");
                    get(elmId);
                });

        _#-->
    </div>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Thanks gautham, I tried the above mentioned options still same issue.

Comment: Can you post the full display template code ?

Comment: updated the code

Comment: I am making rest api call to first get the logged in user, then based on the logged in user i am getting the location property from the user profile. Then using that location i am getting the offset field from location lists. and that i want to use in the calender start and end event date to adjust the time accordingly. Callenge is that the rest call takes time and by the time i have data from rest calls, the page is already loaded. so I am trying to use 'AddPostRenderCallback'. if any other good method pls suggest

Comment: updated the answer. Should hit an alert now.