# SharePoint Online, catch Content Search paging event

Tags: content-search-web-part

Does anybody know how to catch paging event in javascript? I need to add some markup before paging buttons, but this webpart is loaded dynamically. Tried to review "Item_TwoLines.html" Display Template but as I see it renders only `<li></li>` elements but I need to modify header with paging buttons

There is CSR for Search Content webparts as I understand, so I can't catch OnPostRender..

Here is html that I'm adding dynamically (in _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push()). After paging my header dissappears. I need to re-add it every time paging fires and search results loaded:

[image]

Here is out-of-the-box webpart header:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, headers stays in another template, "Control_ListWithPaging.html". Added my html there and all worked.

Related to events - there is something in this post: [AddPostRenderCallback in ItemTemplate is not getting called in Sharepoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/199927/addpostrendercallback-in-itemtemplate-is-not-getting-called-in-sharepoint-online)

But as I understand You have no access to page elements from inside this display template. Maybe I am wrong, not sure

Comment: NB! Always make and modify copy, not original template files.